# Same border for child and parent table

Tags: html, css

I have two tables with similar structure (main and child), they have 3 columns, and child table located in main table row. I want to display those tables like one table with same border, but for different browser the child table border is misplased (e.g. chrome), how I can fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/yCSnf/

.html

```
<table class="main_table" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>value2</td>
        <td>value3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3 class="child_table_wrap">
            <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="child_table">
                <tr>
                    <td>child_col1</td>
                    <td>child_col2</td>
                    <td>child_col3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>child_val1</td>
                    <td>child_val1</td>
                    <td>child_val1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.css

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.main_table {border: 1px solid black; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;}
td {width: 33%; border: 1px solid black; border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;}
td.child_table_wrap {border-width: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of css:

```
td {width: 33%; border: 1px solid black; border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;}
```

to this:

```
td {width: 33.334%; border: 1px solid black; border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;}
```

**Comments Update**

In that case, add a container with a fixed width:

```
.container {
    200px; //Or whatever.
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="main_table" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    //...
    </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vsDwC/1/

Comment: Those changes doesn't fix problem if table width will be 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/vsDwC/

Comment: I've updated the answer and that should fix for when you want the table to be 100% of its parent element.

Comment: Maybe it's my eyes but your second example/fiddle doesn't seem to work.